# Can access web application from browser but crawler application throws 404 erorr?

Tags: http-status-code-404, web-crawler

I am using an application called [Xenu Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) to try and find broken links on a site we host.  When I go to the site through a browser it pops right open.

When I try to run it through Xenu it immediately throws a 404 not found error.  I checked the Robots.txt file thinking that maybe Xenu was using that as a base but I determined that was not the cause.

Does anyone know of anything that could case this?  Could there be security setup somewhere that I don't know about that throws a 404 for crawlers?

Any help appreciated, i'm stumped.

Also, this is an intranet site.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check a couple of things… First make sure the URL isn't breaking it. There were all sorts of articles earlier this week about hashbangs `#!` breaking things. Also, I would look at what your request looks like in the logs vs what this softwares request looks like in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

404 error is thrown when a website page is not find. Please make sure that you set the default document for the site.